# 404 page content for deleted question is different between full and mobile sites

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, localization, 404-not-found

Checked on this [deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322987/problemas-con-materialize-css-y-ajax), mobile view is on the left side:

> [image: deleted question]

The minimum which could be done is to add an item point before “Google search ...” sentence for mobile view.

In the general I don’t see a reason why the wording on these pages is different. For instance:

- Title before the question list
- Using item points for possible list of actions vs for a list of question
- “Google search ... “ vs “Try a Google Search”
- “Browse ...” vs “Browse **our** ...”

Also I noticed that the first sentence probably used from the different sources, because the mobile version of the [page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/931343/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0?__=1845372709) on ruSO contains a translation, in the same time the full version doesn’t:

> [image: ruSO title]